# Display hidden paragraph at bottom of container / page on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

[image]The paragraphs in my div create a second line when hovering -

I think I have found a glitch in how overflow works potentially - if you scroll down to the bottom of my box and hover over the last paragraph, then while the paragraph is expanded scroll down to the end of the scroll bar -

You will find that if you now try to expand the paragraph it will glitch and refuse to expand, i believe because the overflow has already used it's amount for that paragraph. What alternative solution can I use?

All of the CSS is within 'rightbox' which is the box itself and in the 
'nodeParagraph' which is the the initial paragraph and 'extraParagraph' which is the second one.

Thanks.

```js
 
 
 node = ["systems development highways junior", "Dale", "efefefefe efef", "dadadadada dadadad adadadadadad", "systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen", "systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen","systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen","systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen","systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen","systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen","systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen", ]
 
 d3.selectAll('#titleTable').selectAll('td')
      .data(node)
      .enter()
      .append('divname')
      .html(node => {
        if (node && node.length > 35) {
          var before = node.slice(0, node.indexOf(' ', 28));
          var after = node.slice(node.indexOf(' ', 24));
          var beforeReplacementParagraph = node.slice(0, node.indexOf(' ', 24));

          return ` 
           <p class="nodeParagraph"> 
           <span class="hide-on-hover">${before}... </span>
           <span class="show-on-hover">${beforeReplacementParagraph}</span>
         </p>
           <p class="extraNodeParagraph">${after} </p>
         `
            
        }

        return `
         <p class="nodeParagraph">${node} </p>`
      })
```

```css
.totalWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110%;
  height: 200%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 370px;
  height: auto;
  position: sticky;
  left: 152px;
  top: 200;
  z-index: 3;
}

.divname {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.cropcircle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #eee no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.nodeParagraph {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 265px;
}

.nodeParagraph:hover + .extraNodeParagraph {
  display: block;
}

.extraNodeParagraph {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 47.5px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 265px;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
}

.nodeParagraph .show-on-hover{
  display: none;
}
.nodeParagraph:hover .hide-on-hover{
  display: none;
}

.nodeParagraph:hover .show-on-hover{
  display: block;
}

.headerDiv {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1001;
  height: 20px;
  width: 295px;
  background: #fff;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 90px;
  left: 18px;
}

.headerText {
  position: relative;
  color: #1A2F59;
  left: 13px;
  top: 5.5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.headerTextIndividual {
  position: relative;
  color: #1A2F59;
  left: 13px;
  top: 5.5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.rightBox {
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 295px;
  float: left;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  height: auto;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  // overflow: hidden;
  left: 18px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="totalWrapper" class="totalWrapper" (click)="hideBox()">
       <div class="wrapper">
           <div id="headerDiv"class="headerDiv">
            <h1 id="headerText"class="headerText">{{ 'More Engagements' | translate }} </h1>
          </div>
          <div id="rightBox" class = "rightBox">
            <table >
              <tr id="titleTable" class="titleTable">
                <td><div id="divname" class = "divname"></div></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>
```

My expected result is that even when i have reached the bottom, the box will still expand to allow for the second paragraph, meaning there is no flicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is, that you're displaying the additional paragraph **only when you hover the first one**.

When scrolling to bottom, the browser "remembers" that scroll position and jumps to it when the new content (previously hidden paragraph) gets displayed.

What you want to do, is nest the hidden part into the part that should be hovered, so it stays open when the dynamic part is hovered as well.

```js
node = ["systems development highways junior", "Dale", "efefefefe efef", "dadadadada dadadad adadadadadad", "systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen", "systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen","systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen","systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen","systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen","systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen","systems biggest development pot ever in the hands of the most junior fishermen", ]
 
 d3.selectAll('#titleTable').selectAll('td')
      .data(node)
      .enter()
      .append('divname')
      .html(node => {
        if (node && node.length > 35) {
          var before = node.slice(0, node.indexOf(' ', 28));
          var after = node.slice(node.indexOf(' ', 24));
          var beforeReplacementParagraph = node.slice(0, node.indexOf(' ', 24));

          return ` 
           <p class="nodeParagraph"> 
             <span class="hide-on-hover">${before}... </span>
             <span class="show-on-hover">${beforeReplacementParagraph}</span>
             <span class="extraNodeParagraph">${after} </span>
           </p>
         `
            
        }

        return `
         <p class="nodeParagraph">${node} </p>`
      })
```

```css
.totalWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110%;
  height: 200%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 370px;
  height: auto;
  position: sticky;
  left: 152px;
  top: 200;
  z-index: 3;
}

.divname {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.cropcircle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #eee no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.nodeParagraph {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 265px;
}

.nodeParagraph:hover .extraNodeParagraph {
  display: block;
}

.extraNodeParagraph {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 47.5px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 265px;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
}

.nodeParagraph .show-on-hover{
  display: none;
}
.nodeParagraph:hover .hide-on-hover{
  display: none;
}

.nodeParagraph:hover .show-on-hover{
  display: block;
}

.headerDiv {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1001;
  height: 20px;
  width: 295px;
  background: #fff;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 90px;
  left: 18px;
}

.headerText {
  position: relative;
  color: #1A2F59;
  left: 13px;
  top: 5.5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.headerTextIndividual {
  position: relative;
  color: #1A2F59;
  left: 13px;
  top: 5.5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.rightBox {
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 295px;
  float: left;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  height: auto;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  // overflow: hidden;
  left: 18px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="totalWrapper" class="totalWrapper" (click)="hideBox()">
       <div class="wrapper">
           <div id="headerDiv"class="headerDiv">
            <h1 id="headerText"class="headerText">{{ 'More Engagements' | translate }} </h1>
          </div>
          <div id="rightBox" class = "rightBox">
            <table >
              <tr id="titleTable" class="titleTable">
                <td><div id="divname" class = "divname"></div></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Yaaaaaaay! Thank you ever so much! Goodness this question was giving me a complex.. I will actually learn your solution though.

Comment: In my actual code this doesn't work, the extraNodeParagraph doesn't show

Comment: You can't put a `p` inside another one. In the example I wrapped the additional node in an `span` instead.

Comment: Is there anything else you changed? because i changed it to the span which is nested as you suggested and now the extraNodeParagraph does not show

Comment: You need to change the css rule, since the `.extraNodeParagraph` is not a sibling anymore: `.nodeParagraph:hover + .extraNodeParagraph {` -> `.nodeParagraph:hover .extraNodeParagraph {` (remove the `+`).

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you once again. I hope you have a splendid Sunday and a wonderful week.